# Est-ce que les films sont un bon moyen d'améliorer les compétences auditives ?

Tags: ressources, cinéma

Je cherche les films français pour améliorer mes compétences de compréhension auditive. Il faut que je sache si cela m'aiderait améliorer mes compétences de compréhension (et peut-être également la prononciation), avant je l'essaie. Selon mon expérience, cela m'a beaucoup aidé. Est-ce qu'il y a quelqu'un qui connaît des films français qui ne seraient adaptés à un usage éducatif ?